# Why isolated scope(=) not working with strings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular. I read a lot of blogs regarding the difference between `@ / =` for a directive isolated scope, but still i am confused.
Here is a small example i tried.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <title>Directive Test</title>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }]);
    app.directive('personInfo', [function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
          name: '=',
          age: '='
        },
        template: "My name is {{name}} . My age is {{age}}",
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
          console.log(scope.name);
        }
      };
    }])
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <person-info name="deepak" age="25"></person-info>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

`My name is . My age is 25`

I am not getting why name is `undefined` , where as age is coming as 25.
When i am doing `name: @`, everything works fine again.

I am not sure why `=` works with numeric value but not with strings.I know `@` used for one-way and `=`  used for two-way binding, but in my example i have nothing to do with parent scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=` is a bi-directional binding so when you use a string it thinks you're trying to pass a scope variable named `deepak`. To pass strings in you have to wrap them in quotes `name="'deepak'"`.

The reason numbers work is because variables cannot begin with numbers so they're interpreted as a value instead.

If you use `@` it will be a uni-directional binding which cannot be passed scope variables. This will only let you pass values so `name="deepak"` and `name="{{somevar}}"` will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `=`, the directive is expecting a scope variable on the expression behind.

So by `<person-info name="deepak">` you are telling angular to look for `$scope.deepak`, which is equal to `null` in this case, thus the result.

I guess it works if you put numbers is because you cannot name a variable by pure numbers so it does some intelligent guess to replace the value for you.

To use literal string when using `=`, you need to add additional layer of quotes
`<person-info name="'deepak'">`